# Creating Crontab with Python virtual environment

Tags: python, cron

I need to set a Crontab for every fives minutes to run a Python script that's in a virtual environment. What I tried so far doesn't seem to be launching.

In addition. in the cron command I have it activating the virtual environment, but that seems incorrect because I should have to open a virtual environment every five minutes. I'm not sure what the proper way of doing this is.

```
*/5 * * * *  source /home/robothead/scripts/python/venvs/kraken/bin/activate && python3 /home/robothead/scripts/python/kraken/kquest3.py
```

Comment: Sounds like you need more that a virtual Python environment. There are a number of software solutions (like [VMWare Workstation Player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation_Player)) that allow one to run virtual instances of whole computer each with it's own OS that may be required to do something like you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the absolute path for the python3 interpreter. Basically, I meant to try:

```
*/5 * * * *  source /home/robothead/scripts/python/venvs/kraken/bin/activate && /home/robothead/scripts/python/venvs/kraken/bin/python3 /home/robothead/scripts/python/kraken/kquest3.py
```

If that does not help, I would suggest running kquest3.py in VSCode and see the command that the terminal runs. You could then execute that same command in crontab.